# How to run a Swing application on a web page?

Tags: java, swing, web-services, sockets

I have created a Swing application in Netbeans that is basically a chat system (between multiple clients and server using socket programming).

Now I wanted to run this application on a webpage. Is this possible without changing any code?

Answer (score 5):

> Now I wanted to run this application on a webpage. Is this possible without changing any code?

No. It would have to be a `JApplet` to be embedded in a web page, and applets have been effectively killed off. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

On the other hand, a desktop application (based on a `JFrame`) can be launched from a link on a web page using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

### Edit

Scrap that advice regarding JWS, apparently it too is being deprecated as of Java 9.